# How to combine these regex for javascript

Tags: java, javascript, regex, jakarta-ee

Hi I am trying to use regEx in JS for identifying 3 identical consecutive characters (could be alphabets,numbers and also all non alpha numeric characters)

This identifies 3 identical consecutive alphabets and numbers : '(([0-9a-zA-Z])\1\1)'
This identifies 3 identical consecutive non alphanumerics : '(([^0-9a-zA-Z])\1\1)'

I am trying to combine both, like this : '(([0-9a-zA-Z])\1\1)|(([^0-9a-zA-Z])\1\1)'

But I am doing something wrong and its not working..(returns true for '88aa3BBdd99@@')

Edit : And to find NO 3 identical characters, this seems to be wrong /(^([0-9a-zA-Z]|[^0-9a-zA-Z])\1\1)/ --> [RegEx in JS to find No 3 Identical consecutive characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101480/regex-in-js-to-find-no-3-identical-consecutive-characters)

thanks
Nohsib

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that backreferences are counted from left to right throughout the whole regex. So if you combine them your numbers change:

```
(([0-9a-zA-Z])\2\2)|(([^0-9a-zA-Z])\4\4)
```

You could also remove the outer parens:

```
([0-9a-zA-Z])\1\1|([^0-9a-zA-Z])\2\2
```

Or you could just capture the alternatives in one set of parens together and append one back-reference to the end:

```
([0-9a-zA-Z]|[^0-9a-zA-Z])\1\1
```

But since your character classes match **all** characters anyway you can have that like this as well:

```
([\s\S])\1\1
```

And if you activate the DOTALL or SINGLELINE option, you can use a `.` instead:

```
(.)\1\1
```

Comment: @m.buettner : How can I negate the whole expr : to find No 3 Identical  consecutive characters ? this seems to be wrong : /(^([0-9a-zA-Z]|[^0-9a-zA-Z]))\1\1/

Comment: @Nohsib, I recommend you ask a new question, because this is slightly more complicated. However, just to let you know, you can't just use `^` to negate an arbitrary pattern. This only works in character classes.

Comment: @m.buettner : Thanks and here it is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101480/regex-in-js-to-find-no-3-identical-consecutive-characters

Answer (score -1):

It's actually much simpler:

`(.)\1\1`

The `(.)` matches any character, and each `\1` is a back reference that matches the exact string that was matched by the first capturing group. You should be aware of what the `.` actually matches and then modify the group (in the parentheses) to fit your exact needs.

Comment: This needs the DOTALL option to be equivalent