# RegEx in JS to find No 3 Identical consecutive characters

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

How to find a sequence of 3 characters, 'abb' is valid while 'abbb' is not valid, in JS using Regex (could be alphabets,numerics and non alpha numerics).

This question is a variation of the question that I have asked in here : [How to combine these regex for javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095892/how-to-combine-these-regex-for-javascript/13095926#comment17805304_13095926).

This is wrong : `/(^([0-9a-zA-Z]|[^0-9a-zA-Z]))\1\1/` , so what is the right way to do it?

Comment: No he wants the opposite of that

Comment: @m.buettner I see, missed the "No", which I read as short for "Number"

Comment: duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880088/regular-expression-to-match-3-or-more-consecutive-sequential-characters-and-cons

Comment: @GurpreetSingh, I don't think so. The question you linked is specifically about consecutive characters

Comment: @m.buettner I rephrased the first sentence. Let's hope my edits makes it through this time...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends on what you actually mean. If you only want to match three non-identical characters (that is, if `abb` is valid for you), you can use this negative lookahead:

```
(?!(.)\1\1).{3}
```

It first asserts, that the current position is not followed by three times the same character. Then it matches those three characters.

If you really want to match 3 different characters (only stuff like `abc`), it gets a bit more complicated. Use these two negative lookaheads instead:

```
(.)(?!\1)(.)(?!\1|\2).
```

First match one character. Then we assert, the this is not followed by the same character. If so, we match another character. Then we assert that these are followed neither by the first nor the second character. Then we match a third character.

Note that those negative lookaheads (`(?!...)`) do not consume any characters. That is why they are called lookaheads. They just check what is coming next (or in this case what is **not** coming next) and then the regex continues from where it left of. [Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is a good tutorial.

Note also that this matches anything but line breaks, or really **anything** if you use the DOTALL or SINGLELINE option. Since you are using JavaScript you can just activate the option by appending `s` **after** the regexes closing delimiter. If (for some reason) you don't want to use this option, replace the `.`s by `[\s\S]` (this always matches any character).

**Update:**

After clarification in the comments, I realised that you do not want to **find** three non-identical characters, but instead you want to **assert** that your string does **not contain** three identical (and consecutive) characters.

This is a bit easier, and closer to your former question, since it only requires one negative lookahead. What we do is this: we search the string from the beginning for three consecutive identical characters. But since we want to assert that these do **not** exist we wrap this in a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*(.)\1\1)
```

The lookahead is anchored to the beginning of the string, so this is the only place where we will look. The pattern in the lookahead then tries to find three identical characters from any position in the string (because of the `.*`; the identical characters are matched in the same way as in your previous question). If the pattern finds these, the negative lookahead will thus fail, and so the string will be invalid. If not three identical characters can be found, the inner pattern will never match, so the negative lookahead will succeed.

Comment: thank you for the answers with such clarity. In my case 'abb' is valid, while 'abbb' is not. This '(?!(.)\1\1).{3}' return true even for 'abbb'

Comment: Ah okay. I thought you wanted to **find** 3 non-identical characters in your string. But you want to assert, that your string never has three identical characters. I will edit my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

To find non-three-identical characters use regex pattern

```
([\s\S])(?!\1\1)[\s\S]{2}
```

Comment: Well, then my English probably lacks to get these nuances. I thought all three needs to be different from each other.

Comment: @Prinzhorn, the English language or at least the OP's wording was quite ambiguous in this case. But there is certainly a difference "not three identical" and "three non-identical" (`abb` vs `abc`).